# How do you return multiple items from a Slick query?

Tags: scala, slick

How do I go about returning the results of queries when working with slick? Do I return a tuple, or return a single query object, but split up over multiple sessions?

Here's what has me confused: In my index Controller, I create the db connection and implicit session.

```
val db = Database.forURL("db.default.url", driver = "db.default.driver")
db.withSession {implicit session => ...}
```

I can then query my heart away inside of the `withSession` container.

```
db.withSession {implicit session => 
  val coolStuff = myStuff.sortBy(_.name).drop(1).take(10).list
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to get that result *out* of the implicit session. I can't do this

```
def index = Action {
   val db = Database.forURL("db.default.url", driver = "db.default.driver")
    db.withSession {implicit session =>
      myStuff.sortBy(_.name).drop(1).take(10).list
    }
  Ok(views.html.index(myStuff)
}
```

Because `myStuff` is not in scope. I realized that I can return things from  `db.withSession`:

```
val coolStuff = db.withSession {implicit session => ..blah }
```

But what about multiple queries? Should I return them in a tuple?

```
def index = Action {
   val db = Database.forURL("db.default.url", driver = "db.default.driver")
    val results = db.withSession {implicit session =>
      val myStuff = myStuff.sortBy(_.name).drop(1).take(10).list
      val otherStuff = myStuff.filter(_.name != "myname").take(10).list
      (myStuff, otherStuff)
    }
  val myStuff = results(0)
  val otherStuff = results(1)
  Ok(views.html.index(myStuff)
}
```

Is that the right way to do it? I'm having a really hard time finding out what the correct way to go about this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return it any way you like. A tuple is perfectly fine. Note Scala's extractor syntax, which saves you some boiler place. Also note that queries can be specified outside the withSession block. Only .list or .run needs to be inside.

```
val myStuffQuery = myStuff.sortBy(_.name).drop(1).take(10)
val otherStuffQuery = myStuff.filter(_.name != "myname").take(10)
val (myStuff,otherStuff) = db.withSession {implicit session =>
  (myStuffQuery.run, otherStuffQuery.run)
}
```

Comment: How can I use value from the first query as a parameter to the second?